# How to Integrate and send attachmnet (File) over GoDaddy SMTP Client in my Application

Tags: android, smtp, attachment

I am new to this thing. I need to upload and **upload a file(attachment) and send email through godaddy smtp client** from my application. I am clueless. I did google a few things but got no luck. Can someone guide me how i can achieve this. Any link/sample that could help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

This link would explain you the entire process to upload a file.

http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106